# Can't import Theano on Windows 10 with Anaconda's Python3.5

Tags: python, mingw, theano

After installing mingw libpython via conda and theano via pip, I tried to import theano and got this

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

This error comes from cutils.py when it tries to run:

```
from cutils_ext.cutils_ext import *
```

So I checked the cutils_ext folder in my AppData/local/Theano/cutils_ext and found cutils_ext.pyd, then renamed it to cutils_ext.dll, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.
I also used Dependency Walker and found some missing modules but there were too many. Do I have to download all of those .dll files or there's a faster way to get it done?